# Creating a regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am getting 3 kind of strings from a query :

```
**TYPE1 :**["type1"]
**TYPE2 :**["type2 type2 type2"]
**TYPE3 :**["type3 type3"]
```

I wrote a code to extract just the word or sentence but the code is gives an error, please correct where I am wrong in the code.

```
// error in regular expression
Regex _regex = new Regex(@"\"\w.+\"");
Match _match = _regex.Match(temp);
if (_match.Success)
{
    resourceAnalyticsModel.ResourceFieldName = _match.Value;
}
```

Comment: Which error is throwing?

Comment: I am getting it as  "\"type3 type3\"" but i want "type3 type3"

Comment: Now what? Does it throw an error or do you get a wrong result? Be precise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
            string[] inputs = { "**[\"type1\"]", "**[\"type2 type2 type2\"]", "**[\"type3 type3\"]" };

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                Regex _regex = new Regex("\"([^\"]+)");
                Match _match = _regex.Match(input);
                Console.WriteLine(_match.Groups[1].Value);
            }
```

Comment: Present result : "type2 type2 type2

Expected result : type2 type2 type2

Comment: Code is giving expected results.  Not sure what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you use literal strings (`@` before a string) you must escape quotes by double quoting, so your pattern should be:

```
Regex _regex = new Regex(@"""\w.+""");
```

Or, if you don't want to use literal strings:

```
Regex _regex = new Regex("\"\\w.+\"");
```